# Massage JSON response to fit into treeData structure for react-simple-tree-menu

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a React component that retrieves an array of objects (key-value pairs) from a REST API via an HTML endpoint:

```
[
  { 
    "id": 1,
    "grouping1": "first-level-node-1",
    "grouping2": "second-level-node-1",
    "theThing": "third-level-node-1",
    "someData": "data here that is associated with theThing",
    "someUrl": "http://someurl.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "grouping1": "first-level-node-2",
    "grouping2": "second-level-node-1",
    "theThing":  "third-level-node-1",
    .
    .
    .
  }
]
```

I am trying to manipulate the JSON response so that it gets displayed with react-simple-tree-menu.  To generate a [TreeMenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-tree-menu), data needs to be provided as an array:

```
// as an array
const treeData = [
  {
    key: 'first-level-node-1',
    label: 'Node 1 at the first level',
    ..., // any other props you need, e.g. url
    nodes: [
      {
        key: 'second-level-node-1',
        label: 'Node 1 at the second level',
        nodes: [
          {
            key: 'third-level-node-1',
            label: 'Last node of the branch',
            nodes: [] // you can remove the nodes property or leave it as an empty array
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 'first-level-node-2',
    label: 'Node 2 at the first level',
  },
];
```

or as an object:

```
// or as an object
const treeData = {
  'first-level-node-1': {               // key
    label: 'Node 1 at the first level',
    index: 0, // decide the rendering order on the same level
    ...,      // any other props you need, e.g. url
    nodes: {
      'second-level-node-1': {
        label: 'Node 1 at the second level',
        index: 0,
        nodes: {
          'third-level-node-1': {
            label: 'Node 1 at the third level',
            index: 0,
            nodes: {} // you can remove the nodes property or leave it as an empty array
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  'first-level-node-2': {
    label: 'Node 2 at the first level',
    index: 1,
  },
};
```

I have tried categorizing the JSON response based on grouping1 (first level node) and grouping2 (second level node) to make it 'fit' into the treeData:

```
  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/stuff');
    const input = await data.json();
    const output = input.reduce((acc, item) => ({
      ...acc,
      [item.grouping1]: {
        ...acc[item.grouping1],
        [item.grouping2]: [
          ...(acc[item.gropuing1] && acc[item.grouping1][item.grouping2] || []),
          item,
        ]
      }
    }), {})
```

and now I have objects (grouping1) that contain objects (grouping2) that contain the array of key-value pairs.

```
  first-level-node-1:
    second-level-node-1: Array(4)
      0: {id: 1, grouping1: "first-level-node-1", grouping2: "second-level-node-1", theThing: "third-level-node-1"}
      .
      .
      .
  first-level-node-2:
    second-level-node-1: Array(16)
      0: {id: 2, grouping1: "first-level-node-2", grouping2: "second-level-node-1", theThing: "third-level-node-1"}
      .
      .
      .
```

But this isn't the treeData structure that react-simple-tree-menu wants.  How can I massage the JSON response to fit the treeData structure?

Here's an excellent [write-up](https://dev.to/jsmanifest/create-a-modern-dynamic-sidebar-menu-in-react-using-recursion-36eo) for how to get a Sidebar Menu up and running in React, but nothing that shows how to get a typical JSON response to fit into the required structure.

**Update:**

The following is the TreeMenu data [that controls this react-simple-tree-menu component](https://iannbing.github.io/react-simple-tree-menu/?path=/story/treemenu--default-usage)

```
<TreeMenu
  data={[
    {
      key: 'mammal',
      label: 'Mammal',
      nodes: [
        {
          key: 'canidae',
          label: 'Canidae',
          nodes: [
            {
              key: 'dog',
              label: 'Dog',
              nodes: [],
              url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=dog'
            },
            {
              key: 'fox',
              label: 'Fox',
              nodes: [],
              url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=fox'
            },
            {
              key: 'wolf',
              label: 'Wolf',
              nodes: [],
              url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=wolf'
            }
          ],
          url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=canidae'
        }
      ],
      url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=mammal'
    },
    {
      key: 'reptile',
      label: 'Reptile',
      nodes: [
        {
          key: 'squamata',
          label: 'Squamata',
          nodes: [
            {
              key: 'lizard',
              label: 'Lizard',
              url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=lizard'
            },
            {
              key: 'snake',
              label: 'Snake',
              url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=snake'
            },
            {
              key: 'gekko',
              label: 'Gekko',
              url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=gekko'
            }
          ],
          url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=squamata'
        }
      ],
      url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=reptile'
    }
  ]}
  debounceTime={125}
  disableKeyboard={false}
  hasSearch
  onClickItem={function noRefCheck(){}}
  resetOpenNodesOnDataUpdate={false}
/>
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, Mammal is first-level-node-1 and Reptile is first-level-node-2.  Canidae and Squamata are both second-level-node-1 under their respective first-level-nodes.  Dog, Fox and Wolf are third-level-node-1, node-2 and node-3 respectively.  Lizard, Snake and Gekko are also third-level-node-1, node-2 and node-3.  The example I used at the very top of this post may be confusing things.  My apologies if that is the case.

Here is the JSON data that more closely resembles what I'm working with:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "grouping1": "I124",
    "grouping2": "Cross_Streets",
    "theThing": "12th",
    "url": "http://url2.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "grouping1": "I124",
    "grouping2": "Cross_Streets",
    "theThing": "13th",
    "url": "http://url3.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "grouping1": "I124",
    "grouping2": "Cross_Streets",
    "theThing": "4th",
    "url": "http://url4.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "grouping1": "I124",
    "grouping2": "Ramps",
    "theThing": "Ramp_A",
    "url": "http://url14.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "grouping1": "I124",
    "grouping2": "Ramps",
    "theThing": "Ramp_B",
    "url": "http://url15.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "grouping1": "I75",
    "grouping2": "Cross_Streets",
    "theThing": "100th",
    "url": "http://url41.com"
  }
]
```

The goal is to make the above JSON look like this in react-simple-tree-menu:

```
+ I124
    + Cross_Streets
        12th
        13th
        4th
    + Ramps
        Ramp_A
        Ramp_B
+ I75
    + Cross_Streets
        4th
```

Comment: Is it only supposed to be three levels or more? Also, is supposed to be considered a level? I see `grouping1`, `grouping2`, and `theThing` but `someData` and `someUrl` are not? Are these the exact names for your keys that should be considered as levels?

Comment: someData and someUrl don't have anything to do with the groupings.  Just grouping1, grouping2 and theThing.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @goto1 `grouping1` is the highest level (left-most in the tree), once you expand that it will show all the `grouping2` under that, then `theThing` is what gets displayed under `grouping2` when you expand it.  Each `theThing` is unique.  `someData` and `someUrl` are just additional values in the  JSON response that I'm going to do something with when the user clicks on theThing.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does the solution below do what you need?

Comment: @goto1 I was working with the code in the answer you deleted, was grouping things in the opposite order, otherwise your solution seemed to have worked.

Comment: Yes, I deleted it because I noticed it was wrong but then fixed it and it's back now with two results, one as `array` and one as `object` - have a look now.

Comment: Is it good now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that you could apply, however, I am not sure where you are getting the `labels` from, but I'll leave that up to you.

Here's an example with an `object` as the result:

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 2,
    grouping1: "I124",
    grouping2: "Cross_Streets",
    theThing: "12th",
    url: "http://url2.com"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    grouping1: "I124",
    grouping2: "Cross_Streets",
    theThing: "13th",
    url: "http://url3.com"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    grouping1: "I124",
    grouping2: "Cross_Streets",
    theThing: "4th",
    url: "http://url4.com"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    grouping1: "I124",
    grouping2: "Ramps",
    theThing: "Ramp_A",
    url: "http://url14.com"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    grouping1: "I124",
    grouping2: "Ramps",
    theThing: "Ramp_B",
    url: "http://url15.com"
  },
  {
    id: 41,
    grouping1: "I75",
    grouping2: "Cross_Streets",
    theThing: "100th",
    url: "http://url41.com"
  }
];

const resultAsObject = DATA.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  const groupId = item["grouping1"];
  const subGroupId = item["grouping2"];
  const subGroupItemId = item["theThing"];
  const url = item["url"];

  const group = accumulator[groupId] || {
    key: groupId.toLowerCase(),
    label: groupId,
    nodes: []
  };
  const subGroup = group.nodes.find(
    item => item.key === subGroupId.toLowerCase()
  ) || {
    key: subGroupId.toLowerCase(),
    label: subGroupId,
    nodes: []
  };
  const updatedSubGroupNodes = [
    {
      key: subGroupItemId.toLowerCase(),
      label: subGroupItemId,
      url: url,
      nodes: []
    }
  ];
  const updatedSubGroup = {
    ...subGroup,
    nodes: updatedSubGroupNodes
  };
  const t1 = [...group.nodes, updatedSubGroup].reduce((acc, i) => {
    const category = acc.find(t => t.key === i.key) || {
      key: i.key,
      label: i.label,
      nodes: []
    };
    const updatedNodes = [...category.nodes, ...i.nodes];
    const updatedCategory = { ...category, nodes: updatedNodes };

    // replace the existing category object and append
    // the updated object with populated `nodes` property
    return [...acc.filter(t => t.key !== category.key), updatedCategory];
  }, []);

  const updatedGroup = {
    ...group,
    nodes: t1
  };
  return {
    ...accumulator,
    [groupId]: updatedGroup
  };
}, {});

console.log(resultAsObject);
```

Comment: Please see the updated portion of my original post.

Here's what I get with resultAsArray:  https://postimg.cc/z3j0D1ys

It's my understanding that react-simple-tree-menu wants as many results as there are unique grouping1 values (in my updated example there should be one for I124 and one for I75).  Then all the grouping2s and theThings would go under that. 

Here's what I get with resultAsObject:  https://postimg.cc/bd8mjvw0

The grouping1s are looking good but not all the grouping2s and theThings are showing up.

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Rayner got it, I'll take a look in a bit and will update the answer.

Comment: @Rayner have a look at the updated question and let me know if that's it.